# How to Recalculate or Re set the size of childs in GridLayoutGroup in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game i have one GridLayoutGroup UI. for some reason i need to remove childern of GridLayoutGroup and the add new child . my code for removing child is:

```
    private void RemoveAllCards(){
    int childs = transform.childCount;
    for (int i = childs - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        GameObject.Destroy(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
    }
}
```

but after i add new items to GridLayoutGroup the y position of items is start from last item that i deleted. 
so my question is how to recalculate or reposition of my new items in GridLayoutGroup

Comment: Are you basically looking for the `ContentSizeFitter` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is reorder game objects in hierarchy. You can do this with these methods:

```
transform.SetAsLastSibling();
transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
transform.SetSiblingIndex();
```

Comment: thanks but  it makes z position of child -11520 ?! and also `SetSiblingIndex` need arguments that is set it to 0 but nothing change .

Answer (score 0):

Try set child parent to null before destroying like:

```
transform.GetChild(i).parent = null;
GameObject.Destroy(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
```

in your case.

This happens because when you destroy an object, it isn’t removed from the scene immediately. Instead, it’s marked for deletion and removed after the current round of event functions that it’s destroyed in.